# java regular expression on find all .txt

Tags: java, regex, path

I am trying to select all .txt files in known directory.
For example I know the path : C:/../Desktop/
and now I want to take all .txt files which are on Desktop.

So which regularExpression should I use and how can i search it ? I dont know very much knowlegde about java. If you help me i will very happy.

```
String regularExpression = ?

String path = "C:/../Desktop/";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regularExpression);
boolean isMatched = Pattern.matches(regularExpression,path);
```

Comment: If you want *work* with the files, use the tools provided in the package `java.nio`. Don't reinvent the wheel Oracle already build for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Listing files in a directory matching a pattern in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102952/listing-files-in-a-directory-matching-a-pattern-in-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Files.newDirectoryStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
import java.nio.file.DirectoryStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Path dir = Paths.get("/tmp", "subdir", "subsubdir");
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, "*.txt")) {
            for (Path path : stream) {
                System.out.println(path.getFileName());
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

On Windows, build the `Path` of the directory as described for [`Paths.get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...%29). This method accepts one or more parameters which together build up a path. In my example, the parameters `/tmp`, `subdir`, and `subsubdir` result in `/tmp/subdir/subsubdir`. On Windows, you would probably build the path from segments like `C:` and `Desktop`.

Comment: Could you please explain the Paths.get() parameters:
My path is like: C:/Documents and Settings/username/Desktop/
so what should i write in the Paths.get() ??

Answer (score 4):

Here is the answer:

```
String regularExpression = ".*\.txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

`"path".endsWith(".txt")` will be faster

Answer (score 0):

Try this to process txt files, this will take all files inside the root folder and inner folder as well.

```
    public static void main(String[] arg"s) throws Exception {
     File dir = new File("YOUR_ROOT_FILE_PATH");
                    File[] dirs = dir.listFiles();
                    parseFiles(dirs);
}

        public static void parseFiles(File[] files) throws Exception {
                for (File file : files) {
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        parseFiles(file.listFiles());
                    } else {
                        if(file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".txt"){
        //do ur stuff here or call a function and pass this file as argument
                        }
                    }
                }
```